# How to integrate svgo into vite react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, vite, svgo

It's a useful feature in `create-react-app` that I can use svg as a react component:

```js
import { ReactComponent as NotFound } from '@/assets/images/not-found.svg'

function Error() {
  return (
    <div>
      <NotFound className="logo" />
    </div>
  )
}
export default Error
```

I want this feature in my new vite project, but I didn't find any tutorials or blog posts about this.

Answer (score 1):

Plugin [`vite-plugin-svgr`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-svgr) can do this.